# Can i use IBM JsonStore in my android application without Server?

Tags: jsonstore

Can i use IBM JsonStore in my android application without Server ??
In the sample project, assets folder, there is a file called "mfpclient.properties".
This file has the following config

````
wlServerHost=9.109.245.27
wlServerPort=9080
wlServerContext=/mfp/
languagePreferences=en```

Can i use IBM JsonStore in my android application, without providing this config file. Is it mandatory to have a server to this JsonStore ??
````

Comment: I'm using the same values given in "mfpclient.properties" of sample project in the following link https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/JSONStoreAndroid

Comment: By using the same "mfpclient.properties" file from sample project in the actual project, it is working, but i don't know whether it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the same "mfpclient.properties" file from sample project in the actual project, it is working, but i don't know whether it is the right way to do it.